# UI issues when closing and reopening the app in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, synchronization

I am running a synchronization process where I download files from the server into my iPad. When I am running the process in iOS6, the UI looks like this: [image]

However, when the process is running, I close the app and return to the home screen and when I relaunch the app, it looks like this:[image]

The screen blacks out...

At the same time, when I run this in iOS5, it works perfectly fine. But the problem is when I run it in iOS6.

At times, it runs properly returning me the red background.. at times, it returns the black screen... Totally amused by this problem...

What might be the reason?

**EDIT:**

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
     Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
     If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
     */
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
     */
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     Save data if appropriate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
}
```

Comment: Please show the code for how you configure the background.

Comment: What do you mean by closing the app, do you send it to the background or are you killing it at the homescreen? Please show some code of your application delegate and the way you build the background.

Comment: I am not killing the app.. Just closing and opening the app again...

Comment: Black is the color of "transparent" with nothing behind it.  For some reason the background of the screen is not being displayed.  I suspect that you're using some non-standard means to set the background and iOS 6 isn't preserving the non-standardness very well.

Comment: (Note that the title of your question does not reflect the problem you have.)

Comment: Are you using ARC? Can you post the implementation of `viewDidLoad`, `viewDidUnload` and any related methods about the view initialization? Also it would be useful to know how do you set your background in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

When app goes in background OS can reduce memory usage for your app, so background view may be released. Try reloading background every time when you load the view with viewWillApperar method.